Long boot time - Linux Mint 22
I hope you can help me to find out why my boot time is 1 min 25s.
Here is my system info:
System:
  Kernel: 6.8.0-49-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 13.2.0 clocksource: tsc
  Desktop: Cinnamon v: 6.2.9 tk: GTK v: 3.24.41 wm: Muffin v: 6.2.0 vt: 7 dm: LightDM v: 1.30.0
    Distro: Linux Mint 22 Wilma base: Ubuntu 24.04 noble
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: ASRock product: X600M-STX v: N/A serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: ASRock model: X600M-STX serial: <superuser required> uuid: <superuser required>
    UEFI: American Megatrends LLC. v: 4.03 date: 07/11/2024
Battery:
  Device-1: hidpp_battery_0 model: Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master serial: <filter>
    charge: 55% (should be ignored) rechargeable: yes status: discharging
  Device-2: hidpp_battery_1 model: Logitech MX Keys Wireless Keyboard serial: <filter>
    charge: 100% (should be ignored) rechargeable: yes status: discharging
CPU:
  Info: 6-core model: AMD Ryzen 5 8600G w/ Radeon 760M Graphics bits: 64 type: MT MCP smt: enabled
    arch: Zen 4 rev: 2 cache: L1: 384 KiB L2: 6 MiB L3: 16 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 3024 high: 4750 min/max: 400/5073:5693:5230:5383:5540 cores: 1: 3228 2: 2714
    3: 2713 4: 3929 5: 2714 6: 4749 7: 4736 8: 400 9: 2714 10: 3251 11: 400 12: 4750 bogomips: 104400
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Phoenix1 driver: amdgpu v: kernel arch: RDNA-3 pcie: speed: 16 GT/s lanes: 16
    ports: active: DP-1,HDMI-A-1 empty: DP-2, DP-3, DP-4, DP-5, DP-6, Writeback-1 bus-ID: 05:00.0
    chip-ID: 1002:15bf class-ID: 0300 temp: 49.0 C
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 21.1.11 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.6 driver: X: loaded: amdgpu
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,vesa dri: radeonsi gpu: amdgpu display-ID: :0 screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 5120x1440 s-dpi: 96 s-size: 1355x381mm (53.35x15.00")
    s-diag: 1408mm (55.42")
  Monitor-1: DP-1 mapped: DisplayPort-0 pos: right model: Dell P2720D serial: <filter>
    res: 2560x1440 hz: 60 dpi: 109 size: 597x336mm (23.5x13.23") diag: 685mm (27") modes:
    max: 2560x1440 min: 720x400
  Monitor-2: HDMI-A-1 mapped: HDMI-A-0 pos: primary,left model: Dell P2720D serial: <filter>
    res: 2560x1440 hz: 60 dpi: 109 size: 597x336mm (23.5x13.23") diag: 685mm (27") modes:
    max: 2560x1440 min: 720x400
  API: EGL v: 1.5 hw: drv: amd radeonsi platforms: device: 0 drv: radeonsi device: 1 drv: swrast
    gbm: drv: kms_swrast surfaceless: drv: radeonsi x11: drv: radeonsi inactive: wayland
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 compat-v: 4.5 vendor: amd mesa v: 24.0.9-0ubuntu0.2 glx-v: 1.4
    direct-render: yes renderer: AMD Radeon Graphics (radeonsi gfx1103_r1 LLVM 17.0.6 DRM 3.57
    6.8.0-49-generic) device-ID: 1002:15bf
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD Rembrandt Radeon High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel pcie:
    speed: 16 GT/s lanes: 16 bus-ID: 05:00.1 chip-ID: 1002:1640 class-ID: 0403
  Device-2: AMD Family 17h/19h HD Audio vendor: ASRock driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel pcie:
    speed: 16 GT/s lanes: 16 bus-ID: 05:00.6 chip-ID: 1022:15e3 class-ID: 0403
  Device-3: GN Netcom Jabra Link 370 driver: jabra,snd-usb-audio,usbhid type: USB rev: 2.0
    speed: 12 Mb/s lanes: 1 bus-ID: 1-2.3.2:6 chip-ID: 0b0e:245e class-ID: 0300 serial: <filter>
  API: ALSA v: k6.8.0-49-generic status: kernel-api
  Server-1: PipeWire v: 1.0.5 status: active with: 1: pipewire-pulse status: active
    2: wireplumber status: active 3: pipewire-alsa type: plugin
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8125 2.5GbE vendor: ASRock driver: r8169 v: kernel pcie: speed: 5 GT/s
    lanes: 1 port: e000 bus-ID: 04:00.0 chip-ID: 10ec:8125 class-ID: 0200
  IF: enp4s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-1: wg0-mullvad state: unknown speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac: N/A
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: ASUSTek Broadcom BCM20702A0 Bluetooth driver: btusb v: 0.8 type: USB rev: 2.0
    speed: 12 Mb/s lanes: 1 bus-ID: 1-2.3.4:7 chip-ID: 0b05:17cb class-ID: fe01 serial: <filter>
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: up address: <filter> bt-v: 4.0 lmp-v: 6 sub-v: 220e
    hci-v: 6 rev: 1000 class-ID: 7c0104
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 3.18 TiB used: 294.88 GiB (9.0%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Samsung model: SSD 970 EVO Plus 1TB size: 931.51 GiB
    speed: 31.6 Gb/s lanes: 4 tech: SSD serial: <filter> fw-rev: 3B2QEXM7 temp: 48.9 C scheme: GPT
  ID-2: /dev/nvme1n1 vendor: Western Digital model: WD BLACK SN850X HS 2000GB size: 1.82 TiB
    speed: 63.2 Gb/s lanes: 4 tech: SSD serial: <filter> fw-rev: 620361WD temp: 47.9 C scheme: GPT
  ID-3: /dev/sda vendor: Crucial model: CT500MX500SSD1 size: 465.76 GiB speed: 6.0 Gb/s tech: SSD
    serial: <filter> fw-rev: 010 scheme: GPT
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 1.79 TiB used: 264.29 GiB (14.4%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme1n1p2
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 511 MiB used: 6.1 MiB (1.2%) fs: vfat dev: /dev/nvme1n1p1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 2 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) priority: -2 file: /swapfile
USB:
  Hub-1: 1-0:1 info: hi-speed hub with single TT ports: 2 rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s lanes: 1
    chip-ID: 1d6b:0002 class-ID: 0900
  Hub-2: 1-2:2 info: Realtek RTS5411 Hub ports: 5 rev: 2.1 speed: 480 Mb/s lanes: 1
    chip-ID: 0bda:5411 class-ID: 0900
  Device-1: 1-2.2:3 info: Logitech Unifying Receiver type: keyboard,mouse,HID
    driver: logitech-djreceiver,usbhid interfaces: 3 rev: 2.0 speed: 12 Mb/s lanes: 1 power: 98mA
    chip-ID: 046d:c52b class-ID: 0300
  Hub-3: 1-2.3:4 info: Realtek RTS5411 Hub ports: 4 rev: 2.1 speed: 480 Mb/s lanes: 1
    chip-ID: 0bda:5411 class-ID: 0900
  Device-1: 1-2.3.1:5 info: Logitech Unifying Receiver type: keyboard,mouse,HID
    driver: logitech-djreceiver,usbhid interfaces: 3 rev: 2.0 speed: 12 Mb/s lanes: 1 power: 98mA
    chip-ID: 046d:c52b class-ID: 0300
  Device-2: 1-2.3.2:6 info: GN Netcom Jabra Link 370 type: audio,HID
    driver: jabra,snd-usb-audio,usbhid interfaces: 4 rev: 2.0 speed: 12 Mb/s lanes: 1 power: 100mA
    chip-ID: 0b0e:245e class-ID: 0300 serial: <filter>
  Device-3: 1-2.3.4:7 info: ASUSTek Broadcom BCM20702A0 Bluetooth type: Bluetooth driver: btusb
    interfaces: 4 rev: 2.0 speed: 12 Mb/s lanes: 1 power: 100mA chip-ID: 0b05:17cb class-ID: fe01
    serial: <filter>
  Hub-4: 2-0:1 info: super-speed hub ports: 2 rev: 3.1 speed: 10 Gb/s lanes: 1 chip-ID: 1d6b:0003
    class-ID: 0900
  Hub-5: 2-2:2 info: Realtek Hub ports: 4 rev: 3.2 speed: 5 Gb/s lanes: 1 chip-ID: 0bda:0411
    class-ID: 0900
  Hub-6: 2-2.3:3 info: Realtek Hub ports: 4 rev: 3.0 speed: 5 Gb/s lanes: 1 chip-ID: 0bda:0411
    class-ID: 0900
  Hub-7: 3-0:1 info: hi-speed hub with single TT ports: 1 rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s lanes: 1
    chip-ID: 1d6b:0002 class-ID: 0900
  Hub-8: 3-1:2 info: Genesys Logic Hub ports: 4 rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s lanes: 1 power: 100mA
    chip-ID: 05e3:0610 class-ID: 0900
  Hub-9: 4-0:1 info: Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub ports: N/A rev: 3.0 speed: 5 Gb/s lanes: 1
    chip-ID: 1d6b:0003 class-ID: 0900
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 61.9 C mobo: N/A gpu: amdgpu temp: 51.0 C
  Fan Speeds (rpm): N/A
Repos:
  Packages: 2537 pm: dpkg pkgs: 2505 pm: flatpak pkgs: 32
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/insync.list
    1: deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/insynchq.gpg] http: //apt.insync.io/mint wilma non-free contrib
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
    1: deb http: //linux-mint.froonix.org wilma main upstream import backport
    2: deb http: //ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu noble main restricted universe multiverse
    3: deb http: //ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu noble-updates main restricted universe multiverse
    4: deb http: //ubuntu.ethz.ch/ubuntu noble-backports main restricted universe multiverse
    5: deb http: //security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ noble-security main restricted universe multiverse
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list
    1: deb https: //deb.opera.com/opera-stable/ stable non-free
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
    1: deb http: //repository.spotify.com stable non-free
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources
    1: deb [arch=amd64 i386] https: //dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy main
Info:
  Memory: total: 32 GiB note: est. available: 30.44 GiB used: 6.96 GiB (22.9%)
  Processes: 415 Power: uptime: 49m states: freeze,mem,disk suspend: deep wakeups: 0
    hibernate: platform Init: systemd v: 255 target: graphical (5) default: graphical
  Compilers: gcc: 13.2.0 Client: Unknown python3.12 client inxi: 3.3.34

Here is the systemd-analyze output:
Startup finished in 11.941s (firmware) + 1.580s (loader) + 1min 4.421s (kernel) + 7.677s (userspace) = 1min 25.621s 
graphical.target reached after 7.669s in userspace.

Here is the systemd-analyze critical-chain output:
graphical.target @7.669s
└─multi-user.target @7.669s
  └─getty.target @7.669s
    └─getty@tty1.service @7.669s
      └─system-getty.slice @7.668s
        └─setvtrgb.service @7.662s +5ms
          └─plymouth-quit-wait.service @7.657s +3ms
            └─rc-local.service @7.644s +11ms
              └─network-online.target @7.628s
                └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @4.870s +2.757s
                  └─NetworkManager.service @4.303s +554ms
                    └─dbus.service @4.255s +31ms
                      └─basic.target @4.236s
                        └─sockets.target @4.236s
                          └─cups.socket @4.380s
                            └─sysinit.target @4.234s
                              └─plymouth-read-write.service @3.991s +242ms
                                └─local-fs.target @3.989s
                                  └─zfs-mount.service @3.983s +5ms
                                    └─zfs-import.target @3.965s

Here is the systemd-analyze blame output:
2.757s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
2.273s systemd-udev-settle.service
1.295s zfs-load-module.service
 715ms vboxdrv.service
 686ms logrotate.service
 554ms NetworkManager.service
 242ms plymouth-read-write.service
 185ms dev-nvme1n1p2.device
 182ms mullvad-early-boot-blocking.service
 167ms blueman-mechanism.service
 149ms dpkg-db-backup.service
 129ms udisks2.service
 123ms ufw.service
 120ms user@1000.service
 117ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
 109ms cups.service
  95ms accounts-daemon.service
  92ms rsyslog.service
  90ms gpu-manager.service
  80ms polkit.service
  66ms lm-sensors.service
  65ms upower.service
  63ms ubuntu-system-adjustments.service
  58ms smartmontools.service
  56ms lvm2-monitor.service
  55ms systemd-logind.service
  51ms systemd-journal-flush.service
  50ms apparmor.service
  49ms systemd-journald.service
  49ms systemd-resolved.service
lines 1-30...skipping...
2.757s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
2.273s systemd-udev-settle.service
1.295s zfs-load-module.service
 715ms vboxdrv.service
 686ms logrotate.service
 554ms NetworkManager.service
 242ms plymouth-read-write.service
 185ms dev-nvme1n1p2.device
 182ms mullvad-early-boot-blocking.service
 167ms blueman-mechanism.service
 149ms dpkg-db-backup.service
 129ms udisks2.service
 123ms ufw.service
 120ms user@1000.service
 117ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
 109ms cups.service
  95ms accounts-daemon.service
  92ms rsyslog.service
  90ms gpu-manager.service
  80ms polkit.service
  66ms lm-sensors.service
  65ms upower.service
  63ms ubuntu-system-adjustments.service
  58ms smartmontools.service
  56ms lvm2-monitor.service
  55ms systemd-logind.service
  51ms systemd-journal-flush.service
  50ms apparmor.service
  49ms systemd-journald.service
  49ms systemd-resolved.service
  43ms avahi-daemon.service
lines 1-31...skipping...
2.757s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
2.273s systemd-udev-settle.service
1.295s zfs-load-module.service
 715ms vboxdrv.service
 686ms logrotate.service
 554ms NetworkManager.service
 242ms plymouth-read-write.service
 185ms dev-nvme1n1p2.device
 182ms mullvad-early-boot-blocking.service
 167ms blueman-mechanism.service
 149ms dpkg-db-backup.service
 129ms udisks2.service
 123ms ufw.service
 120ms user@1000.service
 117ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
 109ms cups.service
  95ms accounts-daemon.service
  92ms rsyslog.service
  90ms gpu-manager.service
  80ms polkit.service
  66ms lm-sensors.service
  65ms upower.service
  63ms ubuntu-system-adjustments.service
  58ms smartmontools.service
  56ms lvm2-monitor.service
  55ms systemd-logind.service
  51ms systemd-journal-flush.service
  50ms apparmor.service
  49ms systemd-journald.service
  49ms systemd-resolved.service
  43ms avahi-daemon.service
  43ms systemd-udevd.service
lines 1-32...skipping...
2.757s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
2.273s systemd-udev-settle.service
1.295s zfs-load-module.service

Thank you very much in advance!

Have you updated UEFI firmware & SSD firmware. And hub may even have an update. sudo dmidecode -s bios-version &  udisksctl status &  inxi -d Some things to review but Mint different  than Ubuntu defaults, but process should be similar ot see what is not required at boot. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster Advanced changes:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Improving_performance/Boot_process

I strongly disagree with @VlastimilBurián - with your CPU and no HDD's your boot time should be less than 20s (IMO!). My first thought is that during boot time some services can't start normally - which makes the system wait for them. Please post two files: dmesg.txt obtained by running dmesg > dmesg.txt and /var/log/boot.log - OR if there's no boot.log - /var/log/messages.
